# Material transparency issue

Tags: materials

I am trying to edit my model in blender, and I am running into trouble with materials. I've tried messing with the material sliders for the face material, but nothing worked.

This is what my model looks like without material preview on. This is how I want it to look.
[image]

This is what it looks like with material preview. You can see that the face skin becomes transparent so you can see the mouth and eyes through the skin. This is wrong.
[image]

This is what the face mesh looks like, if that matters.
[image]

Any advice would be appreciated. I got this model from DeviantArt, so I don't know how to edit in Blender that well yet. Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: You should link to the model.

Comment: Hello :). These look like shading artifacts. Using "RMB > Shade Flat" could help :).

Comment: hello, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/